# How can I set file permissions for new files in Maildir?

Tags: postfix, permissions, dovecot, access-control-list, thunderbird

So I run debian 10 through VMbox on win10. I am setting up an email server right now and the things that won't let me turn in this quest is that I can't receive mail from the internet though I can send it. The mail is stored in /var/mail/Maildir and subfolders like new, cur, tmp and when an email drops in, this file doesn't have the right permissions and I can't read it through thunderbird until I manually set the rights. All the new letters have -rw-------+ permissions. What can I do to make all new letters have 755 rights automatically? I really need help, I am still new to this and not being able to figure it out drives me mad.

Things I've tried:

```
chown -R :mail /var/mail/Maildir
chmod -R 755 /var/mail/Maildir
```

and

```
setfacl -R -m "group:mail:rwX" $dir                # Sets the effective ACL.
setfacl -R -d -m "group:mail:rwX" $dir             # Sets the inheritable ACL.
```

But still I can't get the permissions right. I use passwd database as a driver so all the users are local debian users like root or alex united by "mail" group.

In logs I have this:

```
Jul 21 21:42:15 mail dovecot: imap(alex)<2920><4nRq+/eqcMl/AAAB>: Error: Mailbox INBOX: open(/var/mail/Maildir/cur/1595355455.Vfe04Idf939M195657.mail.magrega.ru.eu.org:2,) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(alex) egid=1004(alex) missing +r perm: /var/mail/Maildir/cur/1595355455.Vfe04Idf939M195657.mail.magrega.ru.eu.org:2,)
Jul 21 21:42:15 mail dovecot: imap(alex)<2920><4nRq+/eqcMl/AAAB>: FETCH failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2020-07-21 21:42:15] in=275 out=1023 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I enter `chmod g+r var/mail/Maildir/cur/` and everything starts working until I get a new mail which has only `-rw------+` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Maildir is typically stored in a user's home directory and postfix will `chown` the new file so that the recipient user owns it.

If you are trying to store it in `/var/mail` then the user who is receiving the mail needs to be that directory owner, otherwise the `chown` by postfix won't work.  In your question, it looks like that would be `alex`.

Each local user should have their own Maildir.  Trying to dump all mail into a single systemwide Maildir is asking for trouble.  If you really want everything to end up in a single Maildir, then handle the `REDIRECT` within postfix and then let it deliver normally.